# Sparse logical comparison of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sparse-matrix, array-broadcasting

I have two numpy arrays, A and B, representing coordinates of points in a 2D plane. Let's say A is 10000-by-2, and B is 20000-by-2. Both have `float64` dtype.

I want to find out which of the points in first array, A, are in the second (B). Doing this with a `for` loop would be very slow. I came up with the following broadcasting scheme to perform the comparison (ignoring the floating point equality vs closeness issue for the moment):

```
x_bool_array = A[:,0][numpy.newaxis,...] == B[:,0][...,numpy.newaxis]
y_bool_array = A[:,1][numpy.newaxis,...] == B[:,1][...,numpy.newaxis]
bool_array = numpy.logical_and(x_bool_array, y_bool_array)
indices = numpy.where(bool_array)
```

However this would result in very large, 20000-by-10000, boolean arrays which are mostly sparse, i.e, the number of `True`s is much much less than the number of `False`s.

I'm wondering if there's a way to keep them sparse through some switch or property? Or if there is a better way to do this that is fast and doesn't consume a lot of memory? (doing it piece-wise is probably another option, but I guess I'm looking for elegance as well, besides, speed and low-memory).

---

**Edit**: Responding to @Tai's comment for clarification, let's take a small example:

```
A = numpy.array([[0.1, 0.2], [0.34, 0.44], [0.5, 0.6]])
B = numpy.array([[0.05, 0.05], [0.1, 0.2], [0.7, 0.8], [0.5, 0.6]])
```

In other words, A is an array of 3 2D points (3-by-2), and B is one with 4 2D points (4-by-2).

We can see that `B[1,:]` is same as `A[0,:]`, and `B[3,:]` is same as `A[2,:]`. So we have two matches. The final result, `indices`, would be as follows:

```
(array([1, 3]), array([0, 2]))
```

---

**Edit 2**: Previously I said piece-wise is an option. I tried it and it is not any better. Essentially I split one of the two arrays into 100 chunks, ran the logical comparison on each chunk against the full second array, and consolidated the results, in a `for` loop. Unfortunately, there is no way to let the interpreter know that it can use the previous memory (i.e., you cannot explicitly control the garbage collector, or at least it would not be very idiomatic python/numpy), and the allocator keeps allocating new memory for each new chunk.

Comment: What are values in A and B? Numbers? Can you give a smaller example of both arrays?

Comment: "I want to find out which of the points in first are in the second" Please give an example of this statement. Thank you!

Comment: @Tai I added an example to the question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What happened if there are multiple values that are the same? Say `A[1, :]` is equivalent to many other values in `B`.

Comment: @Tai you can assume that multiple matches won't occur. However, the code I included wouldn't break or raise exception even if there are multiple matches. It would simply list all the matches, unique as well as duplicate. Then I can later filter out the indices array in post-processing.

Comment: I bet you'd be able to try using structured arrays then you could try `np.in1d`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind, pandas would be a workaround.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[0.1, 0.2], [0.34, 0.44], [0.5, 0.6]])
B = np.array([[0.05, 0.05], [0.1, 0.2], [0.7, 0.8], [0.5, 0.6]])

dfA = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=["v1", "v2"]).reset_index()
dfB = pd.DataFrame(B, columns=["v1", "v2"]).reset_index()
common_vals = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, how='inner', on=['v1','v2'])

    index_x  v1   v2    index_y
 0  0        0.1  0.2   1
 1  2        0.5  0.6   3
```

Then select `index_x` and `index_y` two columns by passing a list of column names you need, here `["index_x", "index_y"]`.

```
common_vals[["index_x", "index_y"]].as_matrix()

Out: array([[0, 1],
            [2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, this is a nearest neighbors search where you're looking for neighbors at a distance of zero. You can do this quite efficiently using the appropriate data structure; here a KD-Tree is the best option.

Here's a quick example using the arrays you provided:

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
dist, ind = cKDTree(B).query(A, 1)
results = (ind[dist == 0], np.where(dist == 0)[0])

results
# (array([1, 3]), array([0, 2]))
```

This approach should scale quite well for very large arrays, because it avoids doing all `N x M` comparisons that a direct approach requires. For the size of the large arrays you propose, this finishes in less than 20 milliseconds:

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (10000, 2))
B = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (20000, 2))

%%timeit
dist, ind = cKDTree(B).query(A, 1)
results = ind[dist == 0], np.where(dist == 0)[0]
# 16.9 ms ± 530 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```